# When subclassing QTcpServer, how can I delay emitting the newConnection() signal?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, qtcpserver, qt-signals

I want to create an SSL server, so I subclass QTcpServer and I override `incomingConnection()`, where I create a `QSslSocket`, set its descriptor, and call `QSslSocket::startServerEncryption`. At this point I need to wait for `QSslSocket::encrypted()` signal to be emitted, and only after that should my server emit the `newConnection()` signal. The client code would then think it's using a QTcpSocket, but will in fact be using a secure socket.

But **QTcpServer always emits** `newConnection()` after calling `incomingConnection()` (I looked in [the source of QTcpServer](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/network/socket/qtcpserver.cpp)):

```
void QTcpServerPrivate::readNotification()
{
    // .........
        q->incomingConnection(descriptor);
        QPointer<QTcpServer> that = q;
        emit q->newConnection();
    // .........
}
```

So my question is, **is there a way I can prevent `QTcpServer` from emitting `newConnection()`, until I'm ready to emit it myself?**

The reason I want this is that I want my class to be able to be used as a drop-in replacement of QTcpServer, by code that is unaware it's using it, so it must behave exactly as a QTcpServer:

```
QTcpServer* getServer(bool ssl)
{
    return ssl ? new SslServer : new QTcpServer;
}
```

My code for the SslServer class is currently this:

```
void SslServer::ready()
{
    QSslSocket *socket = (QSslSocket *) sender();
    addPendingConnection(socket);
    emit newConnection();
}

void SslServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    QSslSocket *serverSocket = new QSslSocket;
    if (serverSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        connect(serverSocket, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this, SLOT(ready()));
        serverSocket->startServerEncryption();
    } else {
        delete serverSocket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea that could work in this case: redefine the `newConnection` signal in your `QTcpServer` subclass.

If you do that, objects that connected with an instance of your server won't receive `QTcpServer`'s "version" of the signal, only the one you emit directly from your sub-class.

Here's a proof of concept: class `A` is the `QTcpServer`, `foo` is the signal you're trying to "hijack", `bar` is just another (hypothetical) of `QTcpServer`'s signals you don't need to touch.

```
class A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        A() {};
        virtual void doit() {
            qDebug() << "A::doit";
            emit foo(1);
            emit bar(1);
        }
    signals:
        void foo(int);
        void bar(int);
};
```

Class `B` is your subclass. Notice that it redefines signal `foo`, but doesn't do anything to `bar`.

```
class B: public A
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        B() {};
        virtual void doit() {
            qDebug() << "B::doit";
            emit foo(2);
            emit bar(2);
        }
    signals:
        void foo(int);
};
```

Class `C` is a potential client, connects the signals/slots from a `B` instance exactly like it would for an `A` instance.

```
class C: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        C() {
            B *b = new B;
            connect(b, SIGNAL(foo(int)), this, SLOT(foo(int)));
            connect(b, SIGNAL(bar(int)), this, SLOT(bar(int)));
            /* 1 */
            b->doit();
            /* 2 */
            b->A::doit(); // call parent class's function
        };
    public slots:
        void foo(int i) {
            qDebug() << "foo: " << i;
        }
        void bar(int i) {
            qDebug() << "bar: " << i;
        }
};
```

Here's the output from constructing a `C`:

```
B::doit       // this is /* 1 */
foo:  2 
bar:  2 
A::doit       // this is /* 2 */
bar:  1
```

... and nothing else. `A`'s `emit foo(1)` isn't connected to `C`'s `foo` slot, it will never arrive to `C`. `A`'s `emit bar(1)` worked as expected, that signal is untouched.

With that setup, you can emit `newConnection` when your class is ready, `QTcpServer`'s version of the signal will not be received by your user's objects.

Answer (score 1):

To be a true drop in replacement, you probably will need to edit the actual source of Qt, because you normally can't reimplement any `Private` class calls.

If you are the only one using the replacement one, and you control the classes that connect to the `newConnection` signal...

Just connect `newConnection` to your own slot `handleNewConnection`.  When the secure connection is ready emit `myNewConnection` and connect that to the elements that would have been connected to `newConnection`.

EDIT:
After a bit of digging, I found an option of to reconnect a signal:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6820

Basically, you reimplement `QObject::connect`, and then you keep track of the connections and process them the way you need to.  So in this case, you would keep a list of all the connections of the signal `newConnection` and keep it in a list so when you disconnect it you could reconnect it.  Be sure to call `QObject::connect` at the end of the reimplementation.

Another option when going this route would be to go and just reroute the connections there.  When a connection is requested from `newConnection`, move it there to `myNewConnection`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What about disconnecting the signal and later reconnecting it? Is it possible? And no, definitely no rewriting of the Qt sources :)

Comment: You could try it: [`QObject::disconnect`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect).  I haven't done it enough to know it well.

Comment: The problem is that I need to later reconnect the signal, so I need to get the list of the receivers for that signal somehow. I'm posting this as a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14144415/492336.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty hack would be to very briefly block the signals from QTcpServer. Since you know that `newConnection()` will be emitted right after you return from `SslServer::incomingConnection()`, call `this->blockSignals(true);` just before you return. That will prevent `newConnection()` from invoking any slots it is connected to.

To make sure you receive subsequent signals, unblock signals as soon as you can. I suppose the earliest time available would be right when control goes back to the event loop, so a QTimer::singleShot could do it.

```
void SslServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    QSslSocket *serverSocket = new QSslSocket;
    if (serverSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        connect(serverSocket, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this, SLOT(ready()));
        serverSocket->startServerEncryption();
    } else {
        delete serverSocket;
    }

    this -> blockSignals(true);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(unblockSignals());
}

void SslServer::unblockSignals()
{
    this->blockSignals(false);
}
```

The downside of that is that you will lose every signal that could legitimately be emited between `incomingConnection()` and `unblockSignals()`. Like I said, it's a dirty hack.