# Disconnect and later reconnect a Qt signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

Is there a way to disconnect a Qt signal only temporarily, but store a list of the objects connected to it, so the signal can later be reconnected to them?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can block all signals from being emitted from a QObject though. Could you explain your use-case for this?

Comment: I'm trying to subclass QTcpServer, and I need to suppress `newConnection()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14143730/492336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6820

This post discusses ways to keep track of the list of connections to a particular signal which could be used for reconnecting it after disconnect is called.